# Can I detect that an iOS device has external GPS connected?

Tags: ios, gps, core-location

Is there any way to detect that an *external* GPS unit is connected to an iOS device (say running iOS 13)?

We're building a special-purpose app that really needs an external GPS to work well, and want to warn the user about accuracy issues if only the internal GPS is available.

(Of course, we could wait until inaccuracies occur, but by that time it's sort of too late.)

Answer (score 1):

the only way I've been able to do it is to compute position updates per second. the internal gps is 1hz. The external gps that I connect to (garmin glo) is 10hz.

If anyone has a better solution I would like to know.